# Algorithm to Quickly Count the Maximum Number of Matches

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, matching

**Problem:**

Given two sets of nodes, get the maximum number of matches without duplicates.  A match is defined as `f(n1, n2) > t`.

**Attempt:**

```
        private int CountMatches(ImmutableArray<Node> expectedNodes, ImmutableArray<Node> actualNodes)
        {
            var expectedCount = expectedNodes.Length;
            var actualCount = actualNodes.Length;
            var stacks = StackPool.Rent(expectedCount);
            var matches = MatchPool.Rent(actualCount);

            for (var index = 0; index < actualCount; index++)
            {
                matches[index] = Invalid;
            }

            for (var x = 0; x < expectedCount; x++)
            {
                var stack = stacks[x];

                if (stack == null)
                {
                    stack = stacks[x] = new Stack<int>(actualCount);
                }
                else
                {
                    stack.Clear();
                }

                for (var y = 0; y < actualCount; y++)
                {
                    if (GetNodeScore(expectedNodes[x], actualNodes[y]) > Threshold1)
                    {
                        stack.Push(y);
                    }
                }

                var currentX = x;

                while (stack.TryPop(out var y))
                {
                    var nextX = matches[y];
                    var nextStack = nextX != Invalid ? stacks[nextX] : null;

                    if (nextStack == null)
                    {
                        matches[y] = currentX;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (nextStack.Count == 0) continue;

                    matches[y] = currentX;
                    currentX = nextX;
                    stack = nextStack;
                }
            }

            var count = 0;

            for (var index = 0; index < actualCount; index++)
            {
                if (matches[index] != Invalid) count++;
            }

            StackPool.Return(stacks);
            MatchPool.Return(matches);

            return count;
        }
```

**Issue:**

The project I am working on is performance critical, and after profiling the execution, this function is accounting for the bulk of the execution time.  My intuition says there should be a more direct way to just get the count, because right now the function is calculating the node tuples and then counting them.  Is there a better way to count the maximum number of matches that will result in faster execution on average?

**Update:**

- `GetNodeScore` is just a wrapper for a jagged array.
- `StackPool` and `MatchPool` are from `ArrayPool<Stack<int>>.Shared` and `ArrayPool<int>.Shared`

Comment: Where do `StackPool` and `MatchPool` classes come from?

Comment: Depending on what `GetNodeScore` does there might be ways to make this faster, but as it is it looks like you'd have to just try all the combinations to find the "matches".  For instance if `GetNodeScore` is just adding some value in each node together you could create a sorted list of those values for one node list and then for each value in the other node list just find the index of the difference with `t` to determine how many value would match up to be greater than `t`.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Those are using `ArrayPool<T>.Shared`.  I have updated the question to clarify that.

Comment: @juharr `GetNodeScore` is just a function that takes in two nodes and grabs the score from a jagged array.  Since the nodes have an assigned index, it is a relatively fast operation.

Comment: When you say "without duplicates," what do you mean? Do you mean you don't want two of the same score? That you don't want two matches on the same row, or same column? Or are you saying that you don't want to inadvertently count any match more than once?

Comment: So in essence you have an nxm matrix and you want to know how many values in that matrix exceed some threshold?

Comment: @JimMischel mostly correct.  If elements `A` and `B` match and elements `A` and `C` match, `A` cannot be matched twice, so there is only one match.  If we add element `C` and `D` match, then we should pick `{A, B}` and `{C, D}` in order to maximize the number of matches.

Comment: So you have a matrix of `1`s and `0`s, and you want the max set of `1`s such that each row and each column appear once. Gives me an NP hard feeling.

Comment: @user58697 essentially, but just change "once" to "at most once" since the matrix can be m x n.  I know the algorithm I  have works, but was just curious to see if there was a better algorithm or any tweaks to the implementation that would help the execution time.

Answer (score 0):

I found one micro optimization within this method, but was able to help the performance even more by more selectively calling it.  Instead of iterating through at the end, the count is tallied while the search is happening.

```
 private int CountMatches(ImmutableArray<Node> expectedNodes, ImmutableArray<Node> actualNodes)
    {
        const int invalid = -1;

        var count = 0;
        var m = expectedNodes.Length;
        var n = actualNodes.Length;
        var matches = ArrayPool<int>.Shared.Rent(n);
        var stacks = ArrayPool<Stack<int>>.Shared.Rent(m);

        for (var index = 0; index < n; index++)
        {
            matches[index] = invalid;
        }

        for (var x = 0; x < m; x++)
        {
            var stack = stacks[x] ??= new Stack<int>(n);

            stack.Clear();

            for (var y = 0; y < n; y++)
            {
                if (GetScore(expectedNodes[x], actualNodes[y]) > Threshold1)
                {
                    stack.Push(y);
                }
            }

            var currentX = x;

            while (stack.TryPop(out var y))
            {
                var nextX = matches[y];

                if (nextX == invalid)
                {
                    matches[y] = currentX;
                    count++;
                    break;
                }

                var nextStack = stacks[nextX];

                if (nextStack.Count == 0) break;

                matches[y] = currentX;
                currentX = nextX;
                stack = nextStack;
            }
        }

        ArrayPool<int>.Shared.Return(matches);
        ArrayPool<Stack<int>>.Shared.Return(stacks);

        return count;
    }
```